# How can I pass a php variable to another form in the same page?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, forms, variables

I have two forms in the same php page. I have to save the values in the first form and after is saved in the database, I can be able to use those values in the next form.

PHP code of the first form:

```
<?php
    include 'config.php';
    if(isset($_POST['documentRequest']))
    {
        $date = $_POST['reqDate'];
        $name = $_POST['name'];

        $insertSql = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO documentrequest(Person_idPerson, docrequest_date) VALUES ('$name', '$date');");

        //$sql = "INSERT into requestitem (DocumentRequest_idDocumentRequest, Document_idDocument) VALUE ((SELECT idDocumentRequest FROM documentrequest WHERE Person_idPerson = 6), 2)";

        header("Refresh: 2; url=doc_request.php");
        mysqli_close($conn);

    }
?>
```

Here is my first form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal form-label-left" name = "documentRequest" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form" method="post" novalidate>

    <div class = "first">
    <div class="item form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">ID <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <input id="name" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" placeholder ="Type in ID number " name="name" required="required" type="number">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="ln_solid"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <button id="requestDiv" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="documentRequest" >Proceed</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Second form (this is inside another div):

```
<form class="form-horizontal form-label-left" name = "documentRequest" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form" method="post" novalidate>
    <div class = "second">
        <div class="item form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"> Document Request(s)  <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class = "clearfix"></div>
            <p>Minimum of 1:<p>
            <input type="checkbox" name="docs[]" id="doc1" value="Certificate of Residency" /> Certificate of Residency
            <br/>
            <div class = "col-xs-3">
    <input name="d1" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" required="required" type="number">
                </div>
    <div class = "clearfix"></div>

    <input type="checkbox" name="docs[]" id="doc2" value="Barangay Clearance"  /> Barangay Clearance                                                    
    <br />
    <div class = "col-xs-3">
    <input name="d2" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" required="required" type="number">
    </div>


    <input id="a" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" name="a" value = "<?php echo isset($_POST['name'])? $_POST['name'] : "";?>" required="required" type="text">
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ln_solid"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <button id="requestDiv" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="documentRequest" >Proceed</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</button>
    </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Basically, **I need to use the value of ID in the next form so it knows which ID it belongs to**. The next form is basically about the user's requests (a series of checkboxes). How can I do that? Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Park the ID that you need as text in a hidden field.  Retrieve it on the subsequent page.

Comment: Sessions would work.

Comment: If the forms are on the same page, you should be able to retrieve from the submitted value of the first form in $_POST

Comment: Thank you for the idea. Will try to work on using sessions and also $_POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that when you call `header("Refresh: 2; url=doc_request.php");` you are refreshing the page and losing the submitted form data.

---

**If you remove that from your logic this would work:**

In your second form, where you need the value, do this:

```
<input id="name2" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"  name="other-name" required="required" type="number" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '';?>">
```

This will automatically add the posted value to the second form's input element value if the posted value exists

Note that checking `isset()` first is necessary.Trying to simply echo the value would result in an error being thrown when the value does not exist (before the first form is submitted)

---

**Otherwise, you can use `sessions` to achieve this effect:**

At the very top of your php page add:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['name']=isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] :'';
```

Then in your second form do this:

```
<input id="name2" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"  name="other-name" required="required" type="number" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['name']">
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea! Will try to work this one out.

Comment: By the way, do I need to have sessions in my page?

Comment: Sessions are not required for this method. You'd really only need sessions if you need the value to persist beyond this point.

Comment: Okay, thank you again. I'll let you know if it's finally okay.

Comment: @WandaMaximoff Can you update to show the full html for both forms?

Comment: @WandaMaximoff and you're certain that `name="name"` is what you have in your input for the first form? Also, are you sure that your file is a `.php` file and not `.html`?

Comment: Yes. It is a .php file and its name is really name. I also have a php code in the first form. Shall I edit it again so you could take a look at it?

Comment: @WandaMaximoff Please do

Comment: @WandaMaximoff also, are you sure you dont have more than one input in the first form with `name="name"`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99430/discussion-between-wanda-maximoff-and-delightedd0d).

Answer (score -1):

If your form action is returning to the same page you can try this:

```
<form id="form-two">
<input id="name" name="name" value="<?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>">
</form>
```

Comment: This will throw an error if the posted value does not exist, you need to check `isset()` first